# Locating certain files in Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: mount, scripts, hard-drive, find

I see many methods of searching (or finding) files in current directories or even a specific tree, but am unable to locate an option for me.

I have an Ubuntu 18.04 LTS setup with **14 drives mounted individually** (*UUID mounted in the FSTAB, just in case that matters*).  They are all SATA (which doesn't matter I'm sure), but they are mounted separately, so no RAIDS, no JBODS, no other way of linking; why i look at my Files, i see the 14 mounted drives plus the system SSD.

I need to be able to search all these drives with a single CLI for a file with a specific file type.  In this example, let's assume I'm searching for any and all files that are ***.iso*** files; how can i do this fairly easily, hopefully with the find command, but at least with minimal coding rather than a full Perl script or something.  I'm not a total coding noob, but this one has been bothering me.

TIA

Comment: Have you looked at the `locate` file database?  Run `updatedb` and then `locate *.iso` and it will show you everything that was available at the time `updatedb` was run.

Comment: would i have to run this on each drive, or does it search them all in one go?

Comment: It searches everything that's mounted at the time, so long as you have permission to access it.  I generally run `sudo updatedb` to get everything.

Comment: i find that it only searches the drive i'm currently looking at (i planted some in random places to see if they got caught, however, the find command located them all without a problem, so i'll just use that; it didn't take very long, so it's no problem for me in the long run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find / -name "*.iso"
```

which will find (starting in /) all files that end in .iso

You may want to add `2>/dev/null` if there are many directories you don't have read access to & don't want many *permission denied* errors amongst the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
locate *.iso
```

`locate` will be many times faster than `find` command.

If the `.iso` was just created today you will need to update the database first:

```
sudo updatedb
```